# Is this a good place to use a non-Integer for an Enum (against the usual recommendations)?

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to set up an enum to hold sheet metal gauges (thicknesses).  Right now I have:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public enum Gauge
{
    [Description("24 Gauge")]
    G24 = 239,
    [Description("20 Gauge")]
    G20 = 359,
    [Description("18 Gauge")]
    G18 = 478,
    [Description("16 Gauge")]
    G16 = 598,
    [Description("14 Gauge")]
    G14 = 747
}
```

My question is: Does this seem like a good place to break the rule about not using non-integral types behind an enum?

The real world values are like .0239, .0359, .0478, etc. A floating point type would probably be very unreliable, but I was considering a Decimal type. Isn't it a 96 bit integer with the decimal place shifted behind the scenes? Would that should be a reliable value or am I just asking for trouble with this idea?

Comment: Wait a second, I think I've [seen this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211707/where-does-it-say-you-cannot-start-a-enum-member-name-with-a-number).

Comment: you could use a custom attribute to store and return the float/decimal value

Comment: @gunr2171 I know, but I screwed up that question by asking two things in it and now I can't roll back the changes like I do on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Plutonix now that is a good idea. That might be what I should be doing.

Comment: How about using a structure or shared properties on a class instead of an enum?

Comment: @Mike: it is exactly the same question (apart from the different title). You either need to modify that or this.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer but it was closed. Don't use an enum, use a class with implicit conversion from/to double. Predefined values can be stored as constants in that class. You can use it pretty much like an enum, but you can define double members.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it seemed the OP did a bit of mixup with the questions. The old question had 2 questions posted, but ended up duplicating with this new question. I have fixed the older question to be what was intended (and answered), so I believe this question should be reopened, or at least not a dup of the old.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then you can use a class with implicit conversion from/to double:

```
public class Gauge
{
    [Description("24 Gauge")]
    public const double G24 = 0.239;
    [Description("20 Gauge")]
    public const double G20 = 0.359;
    [Description("18 Gauge")]
    public const double G18 = 0.478;
    [Description("16 Gauge")]
    public const double G16 = 0.598;
    [Description("14 Gauge")]
    public const double G14 = 0.747;

    private double Value { get; set; }

    private Gauge(Double d)
    {
        Value = d;
    }

    public static implicit operator Double(Gauge g)
    {
        return g.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Gauge(Double d)
    {
        return new Gauge(d);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Gauge g = Gauge.G14;
g = 0.43;
//and so on, you can pass it as parameter to methods, etc
```

Comment: Clever. I am going to play with this and see I like it in some use cases.

Comment: @Mike: Do with it as you will. Just remember you can't use it in `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Using values like `.0239` are not allowed for enums.

See [enum (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.
>
> ...
>
> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

Comment: Of course, but I have read that using reflection you can make it work with other types.

Comment: @Mike Also, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672102/why-no-non-integral-enums.